# How can I View the output of this animation code in Rstudio

Tags: r

This R code is to create an animated plot, I have run it and it did run but I have not been able to view it. it is said to save it output on `pdf` file though I saw the file but unable to open it. I got the code at [How do I transfer output of animation R package on a beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519298/how-do-i-transfer-output-of-animation-r-package-on-a-beamer-frame/519517#519517)
 because I want to learn how to input `R` animated plot on latex thus I was given this as an example. can you show me how I can view its output either on `Rstudio` or where the code saves it to? If you mean that the output can be viewed on `pdf` that is originally saved to, show me how? I am using Acrobat Reade Dc.

```
brownianMotion <-  function(n=10,xlim=c(-20,20),ylim=c(-20,20),steps=50)
  {
    x=rnorm(n)
    y=rnorm(n)
    for (i in 1:steps) {
      plot(x,y,xlim = xlim,ylim = ylim)
      text(x,y)

      # iterate over particles
      for(k in 1:n){
        walk=rnorm(2); # random move of particle

        x[k]=x[k]+walk[1] # new position
        y[k]=y[k]+walk[2]

        # simple model for preventing a particle from moving past the limits
        if(x[k]<xlim[1]) x[k]=xlim[1]
        if(x[k]>xlim[2]) x[k]=xlim[2]
        if(y[k]<ylim[1]) y[k]=ylim[1]
        if(y[k]>ylim[2]) y[k]=ylim[2]
      }
    }
}


pdf("frames.pdf")                # output device and file name
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", pty="s") # square plot region
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.2,0.2))      # plot margins

brownianMotion(n=20, steps=400)  # 20 particles, 400 time steps
```

Comment: Can you provide a link towards where you got that exemple ? According to [this one](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/animations/), for instance, you must write every plot as a separate pdf file for LaTeX animation.

Comment: I have included the link of where I got it in the question

Comment: Instead of a downvote, why not ask what is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here :

1. you need to add `dev.off()` after plotting so that the current plot is saved to the output device
2. the loop over step is rewriting the same filename for each plot, so that you end-up in having only the last frame in `frames.pdf`. Following [this tutorial](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/animations/), you should rather write separate pdf files to an output folder, then animate them within LaTeX.

```
brownianMotion <-  function(n=10,xlim=c(-20,20),ylim=c(-20,20),steps=50){
    x=rnorm(n)
    y=rnorm(n)

    for (i in 1:steps) {
      pdf(paste0("out/frames", i, ".pdf"))  # save frames{i}.pdf to 'out' folder
      plot(x,y,xlim = xlim,ylim = ylim)
      text(x,y)
      dev.off()                             # Adding dev.off()

      ...
    }
}

par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", pty="s") # square plot region
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.2,0.2))      # plot margins

if (!dir.exists("out")) dir.create("out")  # create 'out' folder if it doesn't exist
brownianMotion(n=20, steps=4)    # 20 particles, 4 steps
```

The `out` folder will be located where your working directory is (use `getwd()` to see it).

Comment: I appreciate your answer to my question. I got the pdf file opened but it is in static image form and not in animation form like I expected. I got this error message when I ran the last statement `Error in brownianMotion(n = 20, steps = 4) : 
  '...' used in an incorrect context`

Comment: I wrote `...` just to avoid copy-pasting the whole code, you need to replace it with the content of your function. The pdf you'll get from the R code will not be an animated plot, it is within LaTex rendering that you get an animated plot from the various PDF that the R code produced.